# Solution of Non-linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a 3rd order non-linear differential equation. 
$$
y''' + k (y \cdot y''- y\,'^2+1) =0
$$
with boundary conditions
$$ 
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{y}{x}  =1 \\
y(0) = 0 \\
y'(0) = 0
$$
I know that it is difficult or may even be impossible to solve the ODE. But  is it correct to say these boundary conditions are sufficient ti solve the problem?

Since, it is a 3rd order ODE and we have three boundary conditions, I think that these boundary conditions are sufficient (of course, assuming that boundary conditions are compatible with each other).

Comment: A remark: that the equation does not contain independent variable means that it admits a reduction of order.

Comment: @Start wearing purple But let $u=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ can only reduce the ODE to $u^2\dfrac{d^2u}{dy^2}+u\left(\dfrac{du}{dy}\right)^2+k\left(yu\dfrac{du}{dy}-u²+1\right)=0$ .

Comment: do you mean du/dx or du/dy in the reduced ODE?